# Scrolltotop button

Tags: javascript, button, scrollto

I have this javascript code for a scrolltotop button! The problem i have is that i want it to work in two different html pages of my site! It only works in one! Everything is the same in both html, the footer, the button classname, so i guess i am missing something in javascript. Any ideas?

```
var target = document.querySelector("footer");
var scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn")
var rootElement = document.documentElement

function callback(entries, observer) {

  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
   
      scrollToTopBtn.classList.add("showBtn")
    } else {
    
      scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove("showBtn")
    }
  });
}

function scrollToTop() {
  rootElement.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
}
scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);


let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

observer.observe(target);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html also

Comment: try `window.scrollTo` instead of `document.documentElement.scrollTo`

Comment: I just found out that when i removed async from <script async src="js/javascript.js"></script> it worked everywhere